# C# How to detect all changes between 2 revisions after signing in PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I used iText7 to sign a PDF document which has form fields. After each revision, I fill in some fields and the signatures are broken as my expectation when I open it by Adobe Reader.

But when I use iText7 to check the integrity with this code `bool checkIntergrity = pkcs7.VerifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity();`, it always return true. I know that it's limitation of iText7 as mentioned in Bruno Lowagie's white paper.

I can also lock or flatten all fields before signing, but my software I'm developing must support all documents which are signed outside my software and I'm not sure whether they do the same me or not.

My question is: is there any solution to detect all those changes at verifying time? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Detecting changes to signed documents is difficult. Or more to the point, the detection as such is easy but the analysis what a detected pdf object change really means is difficult, in particular whether it is an allowed or disallowed change. Even Adobe's code for this has numerous imperfections with both false positives and false negatives.

Comment: Could you please share the code for detecting changes?

Comment: For inspiration have a look at [PdfCompare](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/meta/PdfCompare.java). It compares two pdfs by internal structure. I used it for comparing different revisions of the same pdf after extracting them. It is not yet finished but can serve as a starting point nonetheless.